# using cucumber-junit with Grunt

Tags: npm, gruntjs, protractor, cucumberjs, cucumber-junit

The test setup is MVN, Grunt, Protractor, Cucumber-js. The output is currently in JSON and I need to get a XML of the results. So upon searching I found cucumber-junit. But since the example given is in gulp and we are using Grunt to executed our tests. I am not sure how to use this package.

It really be helpful if anyone can show to use cucumber-junit with Grunt.